# Which window has current focus?

Tags: python, programming, window-manager, window, application-development

I'd like to know (programmatically) which window has current focus. Is there a window-manager independent way of discovering that?

Otherwise, how does one determine which window has focus in Compiz or Metacity?

Comment: Same question on stack overflow: [Obtain Active window using Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is [libwnck](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libwnck/stable/) (if you're just interested in windows) or [libbamf](https://launchpad.net/bamf) (if you're interested in windows and the applications that own them).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. It lead me to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380784/how-to-get-list-opened-windows-in-pygtk-or-gtk-in-ubuntu), which was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you can use is [xdotool:](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)

`xdotool getwindowfocus`

would return the Window ID of the focussed window, and:

`xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname`

would tell you its name.

Comment: I get `xdotool: Unknown command: getwindowname` for the second one.

Comment: You're using an outdated version of xdotool. The one in the Ubuntu repos is positively ancient, for example. There's a more recent .deb file at their site, for certain architectures, or compile from source if need be.

Comment: Not sure about "positively ancient"... My version is 2.20100701.2961, current stable is 2.20101012.3049. 3 months usually doesn't mean *that* much... But if that's the case, so be it.

Comment: I was thinking the one in the Lucid LTS repos; Maverick isn't *so* bad, but apparently it makes a difference here.

Answer (score 4):

try using the wnck lib and then use this code:

```
import wnck
import gtk

while True:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
    screen.force_update()
    while True:
        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration()
        #time.sleep(0.5)
        print screen.get_active_window().get_name()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy doing a little X11 programming, then the [EWMH spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) is what you're after - specifically [_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2550738).

Answer (score 2):

Well if you can ping something back to the shell:

```
xdpyinfo | grep focus
```

Should work.

Edit: For slightly cleaner output, try this:

```
xdpyinfo | grep -Eo 'window 0x[^,]+' | cut -d" " -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

From  info xtool:

```
getactivewindow
   Output the current active window. This command is often more
   reliable than getwindowfocus. The result is saved to the window
   stack. See "WINDOW STACK" for more details.
```

This is what I use for getting the title.  (I an on 10.04)

```
xwininfo -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" |sed -n \
  "2s/^xwininfo: Window id: \(0x[[:xdigit:]]\+\) \x22\(.*\)\x22$/\2/p"
```