# Get Window Title or Application Name with Python

Tags: python, python3, window

I'm working with multitouch and I try to do different stuff on different applications with the same gestures.

I have a python script, basic works.

Bot how can I decide between the applications? How to get the active window title?

Thanks

*Edit System Information:*

- Python 2.7.6
- Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity)

Comment: python3 or python2?

Comment: patrick@pat-workstation:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which window has current focus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25644/which-window-has-current-focus)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below updated version. I'll leave the old answer, to not remove the answer that got the votes.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Wnck

scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
scr.force_update()
print(scr.get_active_window().get_name())
```

or get xid:

```py
print(scr.get_active_window().get_xid())
```

or (not very surprising) get pid:

```py
print(scr.get_active_window().get_pid())
```

Also see here to get [Wnck.Window methods](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Window.html#Wnck.Window.get_class_group_name).

---

## Old answer:

I'd just parse the output of either `xprop` or `xwit` and `wmctrl` (you might have to install `wmctrl` first: `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`). xprop gives *a lot* of information on windows.

```
xprop -root
```

gives you information on the active window, a.o. the window id, and

```
wmctrl -l
```

gives you a list of currently opened windows. Using the `-p` option also gives you information on the pids the windows belong to. Combined you can get all the info you need.

for example:

#### In python 3, using subprocess check_output():

To get the active window (id):

-*using xprop*

```py
# [1]
import subprocess

command = "xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | sed 's/.* //'"
frontmost = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8").strip()

print(frontmost)
> 0x38060fd
```

-*using xprop, parsing it "inside" python*

```
# [2]
import subprocess

command = "xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"
frontmost = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8").strip().split()[-1]

print(frontmost)
> 0x38060fd
```

Once we have the window-id, get the (pid of) the application it belongs to, using wmctrl:

NB: first, we have to "fix" the frontmost id (output) of the command above for wmctrl; the id from wmctrl and xprop slightly differs:

```
0x381e427 (xprop)
0x0381e427 (wmctrl)
```

to fix the output of the function above (using the "frontmost" output of `# [1]` or `# [2]`):

```
fixed_id = frontmost[:2]+"0"+frontmost[2:]
```

then get the pid of the (application of the) frontmost window:

```
command = "wmctrl -lp"
window_pid = [l.split()[2] for l in subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8").splitlines() if fixed_id in l][0]

> 6262
```

---

#### In python 2, using subprocess.Popen():

In python 2, subprocess.check_output is not available, so the procedure is slightly different and a bit more verbose:

To get the active window (id):

-*using xprop*

```py
# [1]
import subprocess

command = "xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"                                       
output = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
frontmost = output.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip().split()[-1]

print frontmost
> 0x38060fd
```

to get the (pid of the) application it belongs to, using wmctrl and the output of `# [1]`

-*(again) using (and fixing) the output of `[1]`:*

```py
# [2]
import subprocess

fixed_id = frontmost[:2]+"0"+frontmost[2:]

command = "wmctrl -lp"
output = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
window_pid = [l.split()[2] for l in output.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").splitlines() if fixed_id in l][0]

print window_pid # pid of the application
> 6262
```

to get the window *name*, using `wmctrl` and the output of `# [1]`
(also using `socket.gethostname()` to split the output of `wmctrl` by machine name)

```py
# [3]
import subprocess
import socket

command = "wmctrl -lp"
output = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
window_list = output.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
window_name = [l for l in window_list.split("\n") if fixed_id in l][0].split(socket.gethostname()+" ")[-1]

print window_name
```

---

[man xprop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xprop)
[man wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)
[man xwit](http://www.davmar.org/sw/xwit-man.html)

Comment: I've only tested for python 2, works like a charm. This is the very first "How to" I've found so far, awesome. Thanks! +1

Comment: @netzaffin You're welcome, my pleasure.